# [cgal]; Segment Fault Error Parallel Code with OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm trying to do a parallel code with OpenMP but I get a segment fault error while compiling. The code is the following one:

```
    int i, j;
    vector<double> xcentro, ycentro, zcentro, x, y, z, r, d;
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
    for (i = 0; i != xcentro.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        //Inicio el valor de r[i] a un valor muuuy grande, muy superior al que pueda tener la máxima esfera de todas
        r.insert(r.begin() + i, 10000000);
        for (j = 0; j != x.size() - 1; j++)
        {
        d.insert(d.begin() + j, sqrt((xcentro[i] - x[j])*(xcentro[i] - x[j]) + (ycentro[i] - y[j])*(ycentro[i] - y[j]) + (zcentro[i] - z[j]*(zcentro[i] - z[j]))));
            if (d[j] < r[i])
            {
                r[i] = d[j];
            }
        }
    }
```

Could anyone please help me?
Moreover,I don't know if my code is appropiate for parallelizing.

Comment: you get a segfault while compiling or when running the code? If it is the first, then it is a bug in your compiler.

Comment: while running. I do g++ in the terminal and get no error, but when I try to open the file generated by default, I get the error

Comment: @ElenaFernandez You have asked several questions recently, but you have never accepted nor upvoted any answer. Please do not forget to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I took the freedom of cleaning up your code a bit. Meanwhile I found and corrected an error in the calculation of the distance: There is a `)` in the wrong position. I'm also very skeptical of you ignoring the last element of `xcentro` and `x`. I think you will want to use e.g. `x.size()` instead of `x.size() - 1` everywhere to not ignore the last element.

```cpp
vector<double> get_r(vector<double> const &xcentro,
                     vector<double> const &ycentro,
                     vector<double> const &zcentro,
                     vector<double> const &x,
                     vector<double> const &y,
                     vector<double> const &z) {
    vector<double> r(xcentro.size(), 10000000);
    
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
    for (int i = 0; i < xcentro.size(); ++i)
    {
        // maybe try "#pragma omp simd" here
        for (int j = 0; j < x.size(); ++j)
        {
            double const d = 
                    sqrt((xcentro[i] - x[j]) * (xcentro[i] - x[j]) + 
                         (ycentro[i] - y[j]) * (ycentro[i] - y[j]) + 
                         (zcentro[i] - z[j]) * (zcentro[i] - z[j]));
            if (d < r[i])
            {
                r[i] = d;
            }
        }
    }
    return r;    
}
```

The `vector` container is generally not thread save (assuming this is `std::vector`), therefore one can't use any member functions that may reallocate the container like `insert`. There is quite a big possibility that your code would run faster even without parallelism when removing the `insert`s into `d`, as all elements after `j` have to be copied over one location even, when there is enough memory allocated for the inserted element.

In fact the serial version might be faster, as this workload is memory bound, meaning that it doesn't encompass enough computation relative to the number of memory reads and writes to profit from parallelization depending on your hardware.

Comment: @Elena do you need the results in `d` array of just the `r` array?

Comment: @Laci If they can produce the same `idx`, there is sth wrong. I have designed it to produce a unique `idx` for each combination of `i` and `j`. It's lexic indexing just with reversed `i`.

Comment: @PaulG. the reason why I use vector.size()-1 is because if a vector has 10 elements, vector.size()=10, but in the loop you start on 0, so you have to go from 0 to 9, no from 0 to ten, I think

Comment: @Laci No, I don't need the results in d array, I just calculate in order to get the radius (r) as the minimal distance (d)

Comment: @PaulG. I'm trying to understand your code and the only difference I appreciate is that you don't use .insert(), right?

Comment: @Paul. I suggest deleting vector `d`, and using a temporary variable instead. I also suggest moving the result vector `r` instead of copying. @Elena this code will be order of magnitudes faster (even without OpenMP).

Comment: @Laci I tried to deleate vector d and use a double variable, for example, but I can't compare  a double with a vector in the if part

Comment: @Elena use `double dist=` instead of `d[idx]=` and after that `dist` instead of `d[idx]`. Delete the line `long const idx = (x.size() - 2 - i) * (x.size() - 1) + j;`.

Comment: @Elena also make sure to use the appropriate compiler options to vectorize the inner loop for your hardware.

Comment: @ElenaFernandez I edited the answer to get rid of the `d` vector. Leaving away the `insert`s is the only thing you need to not get a segmentation fault with OpenMP. Your iteration scheme `for (i = 0; i != xcentro.size() - 1; i++)` doesn't do what you want it to do, as it will not process `i == xcentro.size() - 1` (9 in your example). Did you find the missplaced `)`?

Comment: @ElenaFernandez please consider adding the information about `d` not being needed to the question, so future readers will understand why my code does the right thing by not computing a `d` vector.

Comment: @PaulG. If I do what you tell me in all for loops, the last element of each vector (xcentro, ycentro, zcentro) and ( x, y, z) duplicates y 6 vectors

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "duplicates y 6 vectors". `for (int i = 0; i < 3 - 1; ++i) cout << i << endl;` will print 0 and 1, but not 2. If your vector has size 3, you want element 2 to be processed. You can exchange `<` by `!=` and `++i` by `i++`, it gives the same result here. Only if you write `<=` instead of `<` or `!=`, it "makes sense" to subtract one from the size.

Answer (score 0):

When inserting to your vectors, you are incrementing iterators past the end of the vectors. For example
`r.insert(r.begin() + i, 10000000);`
takes the begining of vector `r` and increments it `i` places. However, at that point, vector `r` is not large enough as the code got parallelized on several threads.
Thus, for example one of the threads might try to insert to location `r.begin() + 2`, while `r` is only 1 element.
You could fix that by pre-allocating your vectors like that:
`std::vector<double> r(SOME_NUMBER)` and then indexing it as `r[i]`.
Or conversely, you could use `push_back` instead of insert, but bear in mind that the order of insertion might be shuffled.

Comment: Even if you fix that, there's still a race condition.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are saying. Do you mean that r.insert(r.begin() + i, 10000000) is not the same as r[i]=10000000? And about the rest I haven't understood anything at all. Could I fix all this by writing at the beginning of the program   V.reserve(whatever);?

Comment: @PaulSanders The other day, looking at my code, I came to think that it was not possible to parallelize it, but I want to believe that it is possible because I cannot find another way to do it.

Comment: I believe there is a way, with the right OMP declaration(s).  I have tagged your question with `openmp` in the hope that the people who know about this can answer your question.

Comment: @Solo I've written in the beginning of the code: ""    const int NUM_INSERTED_POINTS = 100000;
    r.reserve(NUM_INSERTED_POINTS);"" and still get the same problem :(

Comment: @PaulSanders, I think you cannot parallelize this code efficiently, because of the insertions of new elements in vector `d` ( which also depend on `i`). I am afraid the execution order has to be preserved.

Comment: @Elena As a rule of thumb, If you reverse the order of a loop and you get different results in serial code, you cannot simply add `#pragma omp parallel for` before the loop.

Comment: @Laci how can I do it then in order to make my code faster? It is too slow and I need to use like 1.000.000 data

Comment: @Elena You should use a more efficient algorithm. Inserting several millions of elements in a vector is very slow. I do not know what exactly your algorithm does, but I am sure it is possible to find a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: @Elena If I were you, I would post a new question in which I explain what the algorithm does, add a minimal reproducible example and ask the community to find a faster algorithm.

Comment: I wrote an answer that should preserve the ordering without using `insert`.

Comment: @Laci what my algorithm does is calculating the distance between points (xcentro,ycentro,zcentro) and (x,y,z) and calculating the radius of (xcentro,ycentro,zcentro) as the minimal distance to points (x,y,z)

Comment: @ElenaFernandez: should call r.resize(NUM_INSERTED_POINTS), reserve does not create the points but rather just allocates the undelying array.